# "set_varnames=..." in vcd mosaic plots - how to raise numbers in the labels?

Tags: r, label, exponent, mosaic-plot, vcd

I am looking for a solution on how to raise numbers in the labels of my vcd mosaic plot.

**edit:**
as an example i randomly selected the Sex label in the Titanic dataset:

```
vnames <- list(set_varnames=c(Sex="Sex=10^X")) 

mosaic(Titanic, labeling_args=vnames)
```

They always will be displayed as `10^2` and not as `10²`.

For example working with `expression(10^{2})` or

```
xlab(bquote('Zoospores ('*10^x*') per plastic box'))
```

in the normal R plots or ggplot2 does not work for the `set_varnames=` call in `labeling_args=` in the mosaic()-command of the vcd package.

I could not find an answer to my specific problem in the vcd mosaic plot, only answers regarding labeling in ggplot2 and normal plots..

looking forward to read from you guys !

Comment: can  you please provide a reproducbile example of your code

Comment: working on the answer, sorry, i am new to the page

Comment: `vnames <- list(set_varnames=c(Sex="Sex=10^X"))`

`mosaic(Titanic, labeling_args=vnames)`   ####
in ggplot  `xlab(bquote('Zoospores ('*10^x*') per plastic box'))` worked fine to raise the x so that it is displayed in the exponent, i tried different solutions also with `expression()` they always worked in ggplot or R plots, but not in my mosaic plot labels.. Thats why i think @Jaap is wrong in marking this Question as duplicate (yet i am still a beginner in R, so he might be right after all .. )

Comment: Do you have an idea what the reason might be that it doesn't work @Hardikgupta ?

Comment: I just checked with David Meyer, the main author of `mosaic()` and maintainer of `vcd`. The problem is that the otherwise very flexible labeling relies on processing character strings, i.e., it pastes `varnames` and inserts them into labels etc. And it is not possible to preserve `expression`s in this workflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort @Achim Zeileis! I will add the labels with gimp or Photoshop now. Since this does not feel very elegant i always try to solve "problems" right at the root. Here however, it seems to be the only way.

Comment: You could try contacting David directly with a concrete (reproducible) example. I think it should be possible to enter the viewport tree after creating the plot and adding annotation at the very end. Essentially you just `seekViewport()` for the right viewport and can then add `grid.text()` with an expression. This is for example what `labeling_cells()` does internally. But David will know best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hints of two dedicated members of the statistician community - @Achim Zeileis and David Meyer, i was able to find a rather simple solution.

To stick with the example:

```
vnames <- list(set_varnames=c(Sex="")) 

mosaic(Titanic, labeling_args=vnames)

grid.text(bquote('Sex ('*10^X*') example'), y=0.9, x=0.46,gp=gpar(fontsize=21))
```

`grid.text()` did the job. Since you basically add the label afterwards you have to play a little with x and y to get it in place.

all the best,

Alexander